# Elementwise function over entries in two numpy arrays of differen shape

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra

Let A be a numpy array of shape (a,b,c) and B a numpy array of shape (a',b,c). Let f(A_,B_) be a function that maps a numpy array A_ of shape (b,c) and a numpy array B_ of shape (b,c) to a real number. I would like to construct a numpy array C of shape (a,a') with entries given by applying f to the slices over the first indices.
The naive solution is

```
    A=np.reshape(range(2*3*4), (2,3,4))
    B=np.reshape(range(3*3*4), (3,3,4))
    C=np.empty((2,3))

    def f(A_,B_):
      return np.prod(A_)+np.prod(B_)

    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(B.shape[0]):
           C[i,j]=f(A[i],B[j])
```

which returns C as

```
 [[  0.00000000e+00,   6.47647525e+14,   3.99703747e+17],
  [  6.47647525e+14,   1.29529505e+15,   4.00351395e+17]]
```

I'm going to apply this to much larger arrays A,B with an f that is computationally expensive (above f is just a toy example). I usually try to avoid accessing numpy arrays elementwise but in above situation I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Could you be more consistent in describing the dimensions?  I see isolated uses of `a'`, `d`, `e`, and `f`.

Answer (score 1):

For the dimensions in your example:

```
A2 = np.prod(A, axis=2).prod(axis=1)
B2 = np.prod(B, axis=2).prod(axis=1)
Bv, Av = np.meshgrid(B2, A2)
C2 = Av + Bv

array([[                 0,    647647525324800, 399703747322880000],
       [   647647525324800,   1295295050649600, 400351394848204800]])
```